# SQL Join Confusion

Tags: sql

I'm trying to parse data out but am getting confused with the following Join ref

I am trying the following

```
SELECT * FROM `boomscape_osrs`.`item_container` i
WHERE item_id = '13204' AND amount > 10000 OR item_id = '995' AND amount > 100000000
INNER JOIN `boomscape_main`.`game_characters` g on i.user_id = g.name
```

I am basically trying to replace 'user_id' in 'item_container' with the name which is in 'game_characters' which has a column named 'id' which is relative to 'user_id'

Comment: I am notre sure to understand : you have a column id in table game_characters but you don't use it to make them join, why? By the way, can you please provide us your tables structure and the expected result?

Comment: That's not what you're trying, because it  is not valid SQL. JOINs come before WHERE clauses, not after.

Comment: I think you have some bracketing issues with your `where` clause!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `WHERE` comes after joins.

Secondly, your join condition should be `i.user_id = g.id`.

```
SELECT g.name, i.* FROM `boomscape_osrs`.`item_container` i
INNER JOIN `boomscape_main`.`game_characters` g on i.user_id = g.id
WHERE item_id = '13204' AND amount > 10000 OR item_id = '995' AND amount > 100000000
```

You can change the columns in the `SELECT` list as per your needs.